# How do I repeat x amount of rows with 3 columns in each row using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, json, ajax, bootstrap-4

I want to create a boostrap 'card' of 3 identical cards per row and of course x amount of rows. I tried with the following and spent 3 hours and failed.

```
$.getJSON("./listings.php", function(e) { 
    $.each(e, function(i, e){
        if (e.id != "") {
            //create table here

            var html = '<div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">'; // this opens the row

            //here are the three columns
            html += '<div class="card mb-4 box-shadow" style="background-image:url(./'+e.img+');background-size:330px; auto;background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;">';
            html += '<div class="card-header" style="background-color: #5bc0de;">';
            html += '<h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">'+e.status+'</h4>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div class="card-body">';
            html += '<h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">&nbsp; </h1>';
            html += '<ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">';
            html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
            html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
            html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
            html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
            html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
            html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
            html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
            html += '</ul>';
            html += '<button type="button" id="'+e.id+'" class="community btn btn-block btn-outline-primary">Visit Platform</button>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            //end of 3rd column

            html += '</div>'; //this closes the row
            $('.community_listing').append(html); //this is just an empty div to host the rows
        }
    })
});
```

:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is that you can set the wrapper as `flex`. So it will display your cards with device width. and will be auto responsive.

Let me know if you want to strictly show 3 cards per row. I will edit my answer according to it.

```js
//$.getJSON("./listings.php", function(e) { 
var data = [{id:1, img:"", status:1}, {id:2, img:"", status:2}, {id:3, img:"", status:1}, {id:4, img:"", status:3}, {id:5, img:"", status:1}];
    $.each(data, function(i, e){
        if (e.id != "") {
            //create table here

            var html = '<div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">'; // this opens the row

            //here are the three columns
            html += '<div class="card mb-4 box-shadow" style="background-image:url(./'+e.img+');background-size:330px; auto;background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;">';
            html += '<div class="card-header" style="background-color: #5bc0de;">';
            html += '<h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">'+e.status+'</h4>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div class="card-body">';
            html += '<h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">&nbsp; </h1>';
            html += '<ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">';
            html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
            html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
            html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
            html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
            html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
            html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
            html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
            html += '</ul>';
            html += '<button type="button" id="'+e.id+'" class="community btn btn-block btn-outline-primary">Visit Platform</button>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            //end of 3rd column

            html += '</div>'; //this closes the row
            $('.community_listing').append(html); //this is just an empty div to host the rows
        }
    })
//});
```

```css
.community_listing {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .card-deck{
     width: 300px;
  }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="community_listing"></div>
```

[You can also check the working fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/aalok123/rqtkbm8n/1/)

Comment: Oh thank you!! Yes please I need strictly 3 cards per row.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question now. You want the cards to have the same height, which is why you use card-decks.

For the example, I have overwritten the variable "data" for testing and commented out the JSON query. I hope this can help you.

```js
var targetContainer = $('.community_listing');

//$.getJSON("./listings.php", function(data) {
  var data = [{id:1, img:"", status:1}, {id:2, img:"", status:2}, {id:3, img:"", status:1}, {id:4, img:"", status:3}, {id:5, img:"", status:1}];
  var html = '',
    dataLength = data.length,
    rowClosed = false;

  // do you really have elements with an empty id?
  data = data.filter(function(i, e) {
    return e.id != "";
  });

  $.each(data, function(i, e) {
    rowClosed = false;

    // check with modulo each third element and start a new row
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      html += '<div class="card-deck text-center">'; //this opens the row
    }

    // here are the three columns
    html += '<div class="card mb-4 box-shadow" style="background-image:url(./' + e.img + '); background-size: 330px auto; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;">';
    html += '<div class="card-header" style="background-color: #5bc0de;">';
    html += '<h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">' + e.status + '</h4>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '<div class="card-body">';
    html += '<h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">&nbsp; </h1>';
    html += '<ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">';
    html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
    html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
    html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
    html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
    html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
    html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
    html += '<li>&nbsp; </li>';
    html += '</ul>';
    html += '<button type="button" id="' + e.id + '" class="community btn btn-block btn-outline-primary">Visit Platform</button>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';

    // check with modulo each third element and close the current row
    if (i != 0 && i % 3 == 2) {
      html += '</div>'; //this closes the row
      rowClosed = true;
    }
  });

  // if the last row has just two element, close the the row here
  if (!rowClosed) {
    html += '</div>'; // this closes the row
  }

  targetContainer.append(html); //this is just an empty div to host the rows
//});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="community_listing"></div>
```